# SSL not working on subdomain

Tags: dns, ssl, amazon-web-services, letsencrypt

I recently applied `letsencrypt.org` free SSL on my website `mysite.com`

For my DNS settings, I use `AWS` - `route53` feature.
I created a subdomain : `db.mysite.com` and in the subdomain I created an `A` record that points to also the original site.

However, whenever I visit `mysite.com`, the SSL works fine and I see the green logo, but, whenever I visit `db.mysite.com` I get an error telling that the site is not secure.

What is the problem?

NB: If you thing there is a better forum that is suited for this question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LetsEncrypt offers only non-wildcard certificates for now. So your certificate for `mysite.com` is valid only for `mysite.com`. Not `www.mysite.com` and certainly not `db.mysite.com`.

You can get a *new* [certificate that is valid for multiple domain names](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/host-multiple-domains-with-a-single-certificate/20917):

```
certbot -d one.example.com -d two.example.com -d three.example.com -d example.org
```

Keep in mind the rate limits, you might want to try with the [test API](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/) (`--staging`) first.